# NSdate Assuming wrong time zone

Tags: iphone, nsdate

I am trying to convert the following string into an NSDate object:

```
NSString *str=@"25 May 2012 10:25:00";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"asia/kolkata"]];
 NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];


In console : date-->2012-05-25 04:55:00 +0000....it lags behind 5 hours and 30 minutes and assumes GMT timezone instead of Asia...Why it is so?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you see an [NSDate description] printed in the console, it is always the corresponding time in GMT. If you use the same date formatter to convert the date back to a string, it should be in the specified time zone.

An [NSDate description] is what you see if you type

```
po date
```

or

```
po [date description]
```

or you use NSLog to send either one of these forms to the console.

Answer (score -1):

if you are looking for India Timezone you should use:
[image]