# Cannot get the beginning of current day in NSDate

Tags: ios, core-data

I need the beginning and ending of the current day in NSDate format since i have an nspredicate to get the datas between this range. so i wrote down a function to find beginning of current day and this is it

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:now];
[components setHour:0];
[components setMinute:0];
[components setSecond:0];
NSDate *start = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *strFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:start];
```

when i try to nslog strFromDate it is showing the exact starting of current day like this
 2013-05-05 00:00:00 +0000
but i need it in nsdate format so when i try to convert it into the nsdate like this

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *dateStr = [[NSDate alloc]init];
dateStr = [dateFormat dateFromString:strFromDate];
```

and when i nslog it the result becomes  2013-05-05 18:30:00 +0000. i have tried a lot of codes and when i tried to print it in nsstring format i got the desired result do not know what goes wrong with nsdate. If anyone could guide me. Thanks in advance

Comment: `[[NSDate alloc]init]` That will give you the date and time *right now*

Comment: What do you mean "NSDate format"??? `NSDate *start` *is* a date. Why are you using an NSDateFormatter and a string?

Comment: @matt yes but when i try to nslog NSDate *start i don't get the time set to zero i mean 00:00:00

Comment: @matt i mean the beginning of current day stored in NSDate. i beg your pardon if i caused you confusion.

Comment: i get the time as 18:30:00 +0000 when i try to nslog NSDate *start. But current date is ok

Comment: "i get the time as 18:30:00 +0000 when i try to nslog NSDate `start`" Because that *is* the time the day starts. `+0000` is London. You are on Indian time, which is 5:30 earlier.

Comment: This comes up all the time. Can't people google first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442126/nsdate-assuming-wrong-time-zone

Comment: Understand two things:  1) NSDate ***has no "format"***.  What you see when you NSLog it is the output of NSDate's `description` method, intended only for diagnostic logging.  2) An NSDate is (almost) always stored as a UTC (GMT) time value -- without local timezone.  If you want the "beginning" of the current day you need to know what timezone you're talking about.

Comment: I tried to express this a little more formally as an actual answer.

Comment: You are in India, 5 1/2 hours ahead of GMT. You took the current time, and calculated the start of the day _in India_. That's at midnight your time. Since you are 5 1/2 hours ahead of GMT, it's 18:30 on the previous day in GMT. That's the normal thing to happen. Your day in India goes from 00:00 to 24:00 your time, but it goes from 18:30 on the previous day to 18:30 on the current time in GMT. NSDate always displays GMT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and when i nslog it the result becomes `2013-05-05 18:30:00 +0000`

Read that result carefully. The `+0000` at the end is meaningful. It means GMT (the time in London). So this is saying that the time is `18:30:00` in London. But let's say you are in India. That is `5:30` later, which is midnight. And that is exactly what you wanted.

Comment: +1 you can confirm this by `NSLogging` the `-descriptionWithLocale:` and passing in `[NSLocale currentLocale]`.