# Different dates as result when converting from NSDateComponents to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I am experimenting with `NSDate` and `NSDateComponents` and have a code:

```
...
NSDateComponents *newComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
                [newComponents setYear:from_year];
                [newComponents setMonth:from_month];
                [newComponents setDay:from_day];
                [newComponents setHour:from_hour];
                [newComponents setMinute:from_min];
                NSLog(@"newComponents - %@", newComponents);
                NSDate *newDateFrom = [calendar dateFromComponents:newComponents];// here it is!
                NSLog(@"newDateFrom - %@", [newDateFrom description]);
...
```

And appropriate log of used `NSLog`'s:

> newComponents - 
>       Calendar Year: 2013
>       Month: 9
>       Day: 3
>       Hour: 14
>       Minute: 0
>
> newDateFrom - 2013-09-03 11:00:00 +0000

So, somehow I am retreiving an 11:00 time, but I am setting 14:00 at previous strings of code. How it can be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSdate Assuming wrong time zone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442126/nsdate-assuming-wrong-time-zone)

Comment: Probably because of your local timezone?

Comment: set default time zone and try again

Comment: This is not a problem of the default time zone (NSDate does not know anything about time zones). `[date description]` always prints the date/time in GMT. (This is asked at least once a day.)

Comment: Thanks, colleagues, you are all was right!