# Add 3 Hours to an NSDate's Hour

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I want to add 3 hours to my current date. I am using the following code to add hours but it adds 6 hours to the current date.

```
NSDate *n = [NSDate date];
int daysToAdd = 3;  // or 60 :-)

// set up date components
NSDateComponents *components1 = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[components1 setHour:daysToAdd];

// create a calendar   
NSCalendar *gregorian12 = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDate *newDate2 = [gregorian12 dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:n options:0];
NSLog(@"Clean: %@", newDate2);
```

**Result is :-**

```
2013-09-10 12:25:24.752 project[1554:c07] Clean: 2013-09-10 06:55:15 +0000
```

Comment: Your calculation looks correct (apart from naming the variable "daysToAdd" if it contains hours). - But note that NSLog() prints NSDate objects always in the GMT time zone.

Comment: Days to add , but you `setHour` ? You want to add day or hour ?

Comment: i want to add 3 hours in my current date

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSdate Assuming wrong time zone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442126/nsdate-assuming-wrong-time-zone)

Comment: `gregorian12 dateByAddingComponents:components` , is it a typing mistake or that you are adding the wrong component (components instead of components1) here because I just checked your code works fine.

Comment: If you think that the calculation is wrong then you should show the *input* (current date), the *output* (the calculated date) and the *expected output*.

Comment: @MartinR thanks find out my solution please remove flag

Comment: @Rushabh: I cannot remove the flag. - If you found a solution then you can post it as an answer.

Comment: @MartinR i am using Ravindhiran answer and its work :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *strCurrentDate;
NSString *strNewDate;
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *df =[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
strCurrentDate = [df stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"Current Date and Time: %@",strCurrentDate);
int hoursToAdd = 3;
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setHour:hoursToAdd];
NSDate *newDate= [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date options:0];
[df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
strNewDate = [df stringFromDate:newDate];
NSLog(@"New Date and Time: %@",strNewDate);
```

Output

```
Current Date and Time: Sep 10, 2013, 1:15:41 PM
    New Date and Time: Sep 10, 2013, 4:15:41 PM
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDate *CurrentTimedate = [NSDate date];    
NSLog(@"%@",CurrentTimedate);   
NSDate *newDate = [CurrentTimedate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*3];
NSLog(@"%@",newDate);
```

Comment: Adding a time as a fixed number of seconds is almost never what you want, even when dealing with hours. Think about things like daylight savings. This kind of programmings is what causes peoples alarm to go off at the wrong time twice a year!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *newDate = [oldDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:hrs*60*60];
```

Comment: Adding a time as a fixed number of seconds is almost never what you want, even when dealing with hours. Think about things like daylight savings. This kind of programmings is what causes peoples alarm to go off at the wrong time twice a year!

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist: Actually it does *not* make a difference with hours (as far as my test shows). `dateByAddingTimeInterval:3*60*60` and `dateByAddingComponents:<component with 3 hours>` produce exactly the same result, even if there is a DST transition in that time span.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist DST only changes the offset from UTC, not time itself.  The real reason to not use these exact time offsets is leap seconds.

Comment: @borrrden: Even with leap seconds I cannot notice any difference between the two calculation methods. Do you have any reference or example? - The Unix time does not count leap seconds, as far as I know.

Comment: @MartinR Seems you are right "Due to [Unix time's] handling of leap seconds, it is neither a linear representation of time nor a true representation of UTC".  That's disappointing.